# WebDriver Click not working on asp .Net LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, webdriver

I am running WebDriver (2.35.0.0) under MStest and I am not able to get the element.Click() method to work. [I can click normal hyperlinks and asp:buttons etc. no problem] - Firefox 23.0.1

The Click() method does not raise an exception, but the postback that is specified in the markup does not occur [obviously this works fine when tested manually in the browser];

loginlinkButton is of type asp:linkButton.

I have verified that FindElement is returning the correct element.

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
IWebElement loginlinkButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login"));   //.Click();

//Tried this
loginlinkButton.Click();
//Tried this too
new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(loginlinkButton).Click().Perform();
```

The markup that is rendered is:

```
<a id="login" class="tid-login" href="javascript:__doPostBack('login','')">Login</a>
```

I have checked that there are no duplicate id's in the page as well as tried changing the name of element.

I have also tried selecting the element by CSS as well as:

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Login")).Click();
```

Comment: Do us a favor.  instead of giving us the pre-rendered code.. give us the rendered html code. (what displays when you click view source on the browser)

Comment: @RobD the problem might be because there may be a hidden element with the same id. Just a guess. Make sure it is not this problem.

Comment: Not work means what exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the comments @sircapsalot I suspect that it has something to do with that href="javascript:__doPostBack()", the curse of asp .net web forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around:

```
element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

I'm pretty sure that this is a bug in WebDriver, although what ASP .Net Web Forms does with javascript in the href smells bad, it is something that is widely supported by browsers, so it should work through WebDriver

Answer (score 0):

if it doesn't throw an exception probably you choose a parent element. e.g.

```
<div id="login">
   <span>login</span>
</div>
```

had this problem in the past and i selected the span and it worked. in other words if no exception is thrown probably you choose the wrong element.